# Faster Parameter Passing in Delphi/C

Tags: c, delphi, parameters, parameter-passing

i have 2 parts application, Delphi and C, and i have 2 questions
 1. what is the fastest way to pass parameters to Delphi?

```
procedure name(Data: string); // Data is Copied to another location before passing so its slow
procedure name(var Data: string); // Data is Passed by pointer, Faster
procedure name(const Data: string); // unknown
```

1. i wanna pass parameters by pointers in c, i have a char array and a function, i don't wanna pass the whole array, cut a first part of it and pass the rest

   ```
   void testfunction(char **Data)
   {
       printf("Data = %d\n", *Data);
       return;
   }

   int main()
   {
       char Data[] = "TEST FUNCTION";
       testfunction(&&Data[4]);        // Error
       return 0;
   }
   ```

thanks

Comment: If you need to pass string data to Delphi from a C dll, use PAnsiChar  or PWideChar types in the delphi interface, which are equivalent to LPCSTR (char *) and LPWSTR (wchar_t *).

Comment: @Warren `LPCSTR` is actually `const char*`. Normally you would pair `LPSTR` and `LPWSTR` or `LPCSTR` and `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: That's correct. I can no longer edit that comment, so thanks for noting that.

Comment: -1 for a completely wrong premise. Your program is *crashing*, and you're asking about *speed*!? Focus on correctness first. Once it's working, *then* worry about speed. All the speed in the word won't help an incorrect program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi strings reside on the heap and are always passed by pointer. Your first example of pass by value is incorrect. Strings passed by value are not copied. Only the reference is copied. This is possible for strings because they have magic copy-on-write behaviour. A dynamic array passed by value is copied.

Using const when passing a string has the best performance because the compiler can optimise out reference counting code.

Your C code is somewhat confused. You don't want `char**`, rather you want `char*`. Remember that a C string, a `char*`, is just a pointer to a null-terminated block of memory. You don't need to take a pointer to a C string since it is already a pointer.

And you mean `%s` rather than `%d` surely. To pass a C string starting at the 5th character write `Data+4`.

```
 void testfunction(char *Data) {
     printf("Data = %s\n", Data);
 }

int main() {
    char Data[] = "TEST FUNCTION";
    testfunction(Data+4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yea, i meant %s, sorry, does this also complain for c? i mean, passing char * and modifying it inside the function is the same as delphi?

Comment: @killercode C strings are completely different from Delphi strings. In C you need to manage buffers yourself. You can modify the characters within a C string but if you want the equivalent of a `var s: string` in C then you would indeed use `char**`. But then you would need to deallocate the old string and reallocate a new one (if you needed to extend it). No reference counting and so on. I used `char*` because you were not modifying. This is one of many reasons why people use C++ rather than C.

Comment: yes, const is the fastest. It's rare that it ever matters though.

Answer (score 3):

No one did emphasize on the well-known fact that since Delphi 2009, `string` = `UnicodeString` so will be exported as `PWideChar` / `LPCWSTR` and not `PChar / LPCSTR`. Worth noting IMHO, because it may be confusing if it is not clear enough in your mind, and expect your code to work with all version of Delphi.

If you want to *modify* the string content from C library, you should perhaps use a `WideString` Delphi type instead of a `string`. `WideString` is allocated and handled by Windows (this is the COM / Ole string), so you have all the corresponding C API at hand to handle those `OLESTR` pointers. And this `WideString` do not suffer from the Delphi 2009 Unicode break (it has always been Unicode).

Of course, `WideString` is slower than `string` (for several reasons, the main one is the much slower heap allocation for `WideString` - getting better since Vista), but it's IMHO a safe a cross-language way of exporting some TEXT data to and from a Delphi application and library (in the Windows world). For instance, the .Net world will like marshaling those `OLESTR` kind of variable.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a bit misleading I guess. Does it intend to print just " FUNCTION"? If so:

```
void testfunction(const char *Data)
{
    printf("Data = %s\n", Data);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char Data[] = "TEST FUNCTION";
    testfunction(Data+4);
    return 0;
}
```

That will pass the string to that function from index 4 (including) in the array to the rest of it.
By passing char* you are not copying the string in that function's local stack. Just the pointer to the beginning of that memory.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer the delphi part (my C is a little rusty just now and C pointer/array references make my head hurt when I *am* current and up to date)

Strings are pointer and are ALWAYS passed by reference, so the data is not copied on passing -EVER.

However, in the case of the

```
procedure test(s:String);
```

The pointer S is passed, and if you modify S inside the procedure test, a unique string is generated, and new pointer assigned to S, but not the original passed variable.  You can pass string litterals and string expressions/modified on the fly (s+'bla bla bla')

```
procedure test(var s: String);
```

the address to the pointer S is passed,

The pointer S is passed, and if you modify S inside the procedure test, a unique string is generated (if required), and new pointer assigned to S, AND the original passed variable.  You can NEVER pass string litterals and string expressions/modified on the fly (s+'bla bla bla')

```
procedure test(const s: string);
```

The pointer S is passed, and you can not modify S inside the procedure test period. (ok, you can screw around and fool the compiler but it is ugly and hard to do and usually requires a lot of type casting)

Comment: It's a little more complex. Plain pass by value has reference counting overhead even if you don't modify the string.dify the string. Using const avoids this.

Comment: @David Heffernan -> ah yes, I forgot they increment a memory value.  Still, significantly less than the full copy the question asker thought was happening.

Comment: Well yes, less than the full copy which doesn't happen!  ;-)  I'd be astounded if the difference between plain by value and const was significant.

Comment: @David: But, of course, there is also the semantic value of having a pure input parameter declared as `const`.

Comment: @Andreas Of course. I had my blinkers on due to the nature of the question.